# R- Random forest predict fails with NAs in predictors

Tags: r, random-forest, na

The documentation (If I'm reading it correctly) says that the random forest predict function produces NA predictions if it encounters NA predictors for certain observations.

> NOTE: If the object inherits from randomForest.formula, then any data
>   with NA are silently omitted from the prediction. The returned value
>   will contain NA correspondingly in the aggregated and individual tree
>   predictions (if requested), but not in the proximity or node matrices

However, if I try to use the predict function on a dataset with some NA's in predictors [NA's in 7 observations out of 2688] I encounter the following error condition, and prediction fails.

> Error in predict.randomForest(model,
>   new.ds) :   missing values in newdata

There is a slightly messy work-around that I would like to avoid if possible.

Am I doing/reading something wrong? Does it have to do something with the `"inherits from randomForest.formula"` clause?

Answer (score 0):

Using some examples from the documentation:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- data.frame(x1=gl(32, 5), x2=runif(160), y=rnorm(160))
rf1 <- randomForest(x[-3], x[[3]], ntree=10)
> inherits(rf1,"randomForest.formula")
[1] FALSE

> iris.rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=iris, importance=TRUE,
                         proximity=TRUE)
> inherits(iris.rf,"randomForest.formula")
[1] TRUE
```

So you probably called `randomForest` without using the formula interface to fit your model.

Comment: Thanks! Any ideas why this would be the case? The documentation says that using a formula in training can be slower on big datasets, which is why I don't use a formula (plus I already have trained models, I don't want to retrain). Any other work-arounds?

Comment: @user997943 I don't know why. It may simply be an oversight, or there could be a reason. I can't think of a reason off the top of my head, though. It would be a fairly simple change, so it might be worth emailing the maintainer to ask. At the very least, they would know the "why", if there is in fact a reason.

Comment: @user997943 One could always simply call `na.omit` on your data yourself when passing it to `predict`.

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm doing at the moment- but because of the structure of the code I have to do some messy acrobatics to get the right predictions back. Will email the developer